Stream Huggingface Text Generation Response Via Websocket
So I am new to working with websockets and seem to be at a snag with my current code base. Essentially, I have a React frontend where the user asks a question and supplies some parameters, this payload is then sent to a FastAPI backend endpoint which handles the generation of the response. I would like to be able to stream the response to the frontend but am having some difficulty in determining how to pass the response from the POST method to the Websocket method. Please see code below for further details. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.
BACKEND
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    
    current_output = "THIS SHOULD BE THE OUTPUT OF THE GENERATOR"
    for char in current_output:
        await websocket.send_text(char)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    
    await websocket.close()

@app.post("/qa")
async def qa_generator(request: QARequest, current_user: User = Depends(verify_token)):
    if request.parameters is None:
        return JSONResponse(content=json.dumps({'error': 'Invalid request parameters'}), status_code=400)
    
    task='qa'
    model_type = request.parameters['model']['active_model']
    
    # instantiate the generator based on the model type
    logger.info(f"Generating text with model: {model_type}")
    if model_type == 'TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v1.0' :
        generator = TinyLlamaGenerator.get_instance()
    elif model_type == 'Phi-3-mini-128k-instruct':
        generator = Phi3MiniGenerator.get_instance()
    elif model_type == 'Zephyr-7B-Beta':
        generator = ZephyrGenerator.get_instance()
    elif model_type == 'Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2':
        generator = MistralGenerator.get_instance()
    elif model_type == 'Llama-2-13B-fp16':
        generator = Llama2Generator.get_instance()
    else:
        logger.error(f"Invalid model type: {model_type}")
        return JSONResponse(content=json.dumps({'error': 'Invalid model type'}), status_code=400)

    # handles cleaning up memory before loading a new model when running in local environment
    if os.getenv('LOCAL_ENVIRONMENT').lower() == 'true':
        global current_generator
        if current_generator is None:
            logger.info(f"Initializing model: {generator.__class__.__name__}")
            generator.init_tokenizer()
            generator.init_model()
            current_generator = generator
        elif current_generator != generator:
            clean_up(current_generator)
            logger.info(f"Initializing model: {generator.__class__.__name__}")
            generator.init_tokenizer()
            generator.init_model()
            current_generator = generator
        
    # run the pipeline to retrieve documents
    retriever_params = {k: v for k, v in request.parameters.items() if k != 'model'}
    results = PIPELINE.run(retriever_params)  

    # build the template and generate the response
    template = QATemplate()
    inputs = template.build_template(request.prompt, results['ranker']['documents'])  

    generator_params = {k: v for k, v in request.parameters['model'].items() if k != 'active_model'}
    
    for result in generator.generate(inputs, **generator_params):
        # HOW DO I PASS THE OUTPUT TO THE WEBSOCKET?

FRONTEND
import { useState, useContext, Fragment, useEffect } from "react"
import { AuthenticationContext } from "../../contexts/AuthenticationContext"
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"
import { faGears } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
import { toast } from "react-toastify"
import { GenerativeAPIURL, WebSocketURL} from "../../constants"
import { deepCopy } from "../../helpers/js/utilities"
import Offcanvas from "react-bootstrap/Offcanvas"
import ThinkingSpinner from "../spinners/ThinkingSpinner"
import QuestionAnsweringParametersForm from "../forms/QuestionAnsweringParametersForm"
import axios from "axios"
import styles from "../../styles/ParametersOffcanvas.module.css"

const QuestionAnswering = () => {
    const {access_token} = useContext(AuthenticationContext)
    const [query, setQuery] = useState("")
    const [results, setResults] = useState(null)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)    
    const defaultParameters = {
        'model': {
            'active_model': {'value': 'TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v1.0', 'label': 'TinyLlama-1.1B-Chat-v1.0'},
            'max_new_tokens': 128,
            'temperature': 0.25,
            'top_k': 48
        },
        'retriever': {
            'top_k': 3,
            'filters': {}
        },
        'ranker': {
            'top_k': 3
        }
    }
    const [parameters, setParameters] = useState(defaultParameters)
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        const ws = new WebSocket(WebSocketURL)
        
        ws.onopen = () => {
            console.log("Connected to websocket")
        }
        
        ws.onmessage = (event) => {
            const message = event.data
            setMessage(prev => prev + message)
        }

        return () => {
            ws.close()
        }
    }, [])


    const updateParameters = (node, key, value) => {
        console.log(node, key, value)
        const currParams = {...parameters}
        if (node === "retriever" && key === "filters") {
            const filterKey = Object.keys(value)[0]
            const filterValue = value[filterKey]

            if (currParams[node][key].length === 0 || !currParams[node][key][filterKey]) {
                currParams[node][key][filterKey] = []
            }

            if (!currParams[node][key][filterKey].includes(filterValue)) {
                currParams[node][key][filterKey].push(filterValue)
            }

        } else {
            currParams[node][key] = value
        }

        setParameters(currParams)
    }

    const removeFilter = (key, value) => {
        const currParams = {...parameters}
        const filterIndex = currParams.retriever.filters[key].indexOf(value)
        currParams.retriever.filters[key].splice(filterIndex, 1)

        if (currParams.retriever.filters[key].length === 0) {
            delete currParams.retriever.filters[key]
        }

        setParameters(currParams)
    }

    const resetParameters = () => {
        setParameters(defaultParameters)
    }

    const validateForm = () => {
        if (query === "") {
            toast.error("Please provide a query.")
            return false
        }

        if (!parameters.model.active_model) {
            toast.error("Please select a model.")
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    const buildPayload = () => {
        const params = deepCopy(parameters)
        const filters = {'operator': 'AND', 'conditions': []}
        Object.keys(params['retriever']['filters']).forEach(key => {
            filters['conditions'].push({'field': `meta.${key}`, 'operator': "in", 'value': params['retriever']['filters'][key]})
        })
        params['retriever']['filters'] = filters

        params['text_embedder'] = {'text': query}
        params['model']['active_model'] = params['model']['active_model']['value']
        params['sparse_retriever'] = {'query': query, ...params['retriever']}
        params['dense_retriever'] = {...params['retriever']}
        params['ranker'] = {'query': query, ...params['ranker']}
        delete params['retriever']

        const payload = {'prompt': query, 'parameters': params}

        return payload
    }

    const handleShow = () => {
        setShow(true)
    }

    const handleClose = () => {
        setShow(false)
    }

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setQuery(event.target.value)
    }

    const handleClear = () => {
        setQuery("")
        setResults(null)
        setLoading(false)
    }
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        
        // setResults(null)
        // setLoading(true)
        if (validateForm()) {
            const payload = buildPayload()
            axios.post(`${GenerativeAPIURL}/qa`, payload, {
                headers: { 
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            // .then(res => {
            //     if (!res.status === 200) {
            //         return res.json().then(err => { throw err })
            //     }
            //     return res.data
            // })
            // .then(data => {
            //     setResults(data)
            //     setLoading(false)
            // })
            .catch(err => {
                toast.error(err.detail)
            })
        }
    }
    
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <div className="container-fluid mt-3">
                <button type="button" className="btn float-end" title="Adjust Pipeline Parameters" onClick={handleShow}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGears} size="2xl"/>
                </button>
                <Offcanvas show={show} onHide={handleClose} placement="end" scroll={true} backdrop="static" className={`${styles.offcanvas}`}>
                    <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
                        <Offcanvas.Title>Pipeline Parameters</Offcanvas.Title>
                    </Offcanvas.Header>
                    <Offcanvas.Body>
                        <QuestionAnsweringParametersForm access_token={access_token} onReset={resetParameters} onUpdate={updateParameters} onRemove={removeFilter} parameters={parameters}/>
                    </Offcanvas.Body>
                </Offcanvas>
            </div>
            <div className="container-fluid" style={{marginTop: "150px"}}>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12 px-5">
                        <h1>Question Answering</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row mt-3">
                    <div className="col-md-12 px-5">
                        <form>
                            <div className="input-group">
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" value={query} placeholder="Please provide a prompt..." aria-label="QA prompt input" onChange={handleChange}/>
                                <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Run</button>
                                <button className="btn btn-danger" type="button" onClick={handleClear}>Clear</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row mt-3">
                    <div className="col-md-12 px-5 pt-3">
                        {loading && <ThinkingSpinner/>}
                        {results &&
                        <div className="card mt-3">
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <p className="card-text" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: results}}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="container-fluid mt-3">
                <h1>Websocket Example</h1>
                <p>{message}</p>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
export default QuestionAnswering


websockets are needed for bi-directional communication. for this, server-sent-events seem enough. e.g. I'm using https://github.com/lukeed/fetch-event-stream
